# how can I insert a global variable within a field?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello first of all I explain what I have in my hands.
Two masks, in mask A, there is the "user" field and other fields (what interests me is "user"). While in Mask B it would be the login, with username and password.

When I enter a User in Mask A, I automatically open the Login Form with which I identify who accesses. In this way I would like to take (when the credentials are entered correctly) username of the person who logs in and put it with "User" in Mask A.

I created a global variable "Username1".
This is the code I did test and the message I used to understand works. But I cannot use it by putting it in the box I would like.

```
Private Sub Employee_AfterUpdate()

DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="login", WindowMode:=acDialog
MsgBox username1

End Sub
```

This is the global variable.

```
  Option Compare Database
  Option Explicit

  Public username1 As String
```

I tried this too:

```
Private Sub Employee_AfterUpdate()
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="login", WindowMode:=acDialog
MsgBox username1
Me.Employee_Label = username1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
DoCmd.OpenForm "login"
End Sub
```

Comment: `Me.Employee_Label.Caption = username1` will assign value of Global variable to field but where do you assign value to global variable?

Comment: @Santosh
I would like to assign the global variable into a comboBox.
I tried with `Me.Employee_Label.Caption = username1` but it changed the title of the label and not the input text.

Thenm i tried with `Me.Employee.Value = username1` but it gave me a run-time error 2113, where the value you enteres is not valid for this field.

Comment: What is the value in username1 variable? Whats the row source for combo box?

Comment: @Santosh Thank you.
`Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public username1 As String`
This is the module of Global variable Username1.
The row source of combobox is `SELECT [Employees Extended].ID, [Employees Extended].[Employee Name] FROM [Employees Extended]; `

Comment: I saw you have declared a global variable but want to make sure you have used it correctly.  Do you set the value to this variable `Username1` anywhere?             What does `MsgBox username1` returns?

Comment: @Santosh Well, the `MsgBox username1` is on **Employee_AfterUpdate()**
When i enter username and password, i will press the button OK, a Message Box appears with the username i entered. 
So, i think this is fine.